# Multi channel I2S vs TDM

Tags: i2s, digital-audio

I need to receive 8 channels of 24 bits at 48KHz. So I have two possibilities to accomplish that: either using 4 I2S or TDM.

I would like to understand the difference in clock rates between I2S and TDM. For example: in TDM mode the bit rate is 24 x 48KHz x 8 = 9.216 Mbps. In I2S mode the bit rate is slower once it transmits just two channels : 24 x 48KHz x 2 = 2.304 Mbps.

Is the information above correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes the calculations are correct, assuming what the hardware you are using can achieve. However, depending on the devices, using 24 bits per channel may not be possible, and the 24 active bits must be sent in 32 bit frames. And not all devices can do TDM or four I2S channels simultaneously.

Comment: Thank you. The TDM or four I2S channels will be not simultaneously because I will choose one mode. The BCLK frequency when used the I2S mode is four times slower than TDM mode???

Comment: Yes as TDM has one data wire and I2S has 4 data wires when 8 channels are being transferred, so clock has to change accordingly.